# How do you increase badge size/font size in bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

How do you increase a badge size in bootstrap 4?

I have tried to put in in heading (`<h3></h3>`) blocks, but that changes the display to `block`, which is not what I need (and I guess heading should be reserved to... headings).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Place the badge inside a heading element, inside an element with class `lead`, or make your own sizing class in a custom stylesheet or embedded style element:

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.badge.even-larger-badge {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<h2><span class="badge badge-primary">Heading 2</span></h2>
<h3><span class="badge badge-primary">Heading 3</span></h3>

<p>
  <span class="badge badge-primary">Regular</span>
  <span class="lead"><span class="badge badge-secondary">Lead</span></span>
  <span class="badge badge-primary even-larger-badge">Custom</span>
</p>
```